# Applying a filter to a form in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, vba

IN MSAccess, I have a report which summarizes the records.  I want to be able to click the 'Formdate" field on the report and open the corresponding record in a "MAF View" form.

The following code opens the "MAF View" form, but applies the filter to the report instead of the form.  How do I apply the filter to the form instead?

```
Dim strFilter As Variant
strFilter = "[Formdate] = #" & Format(Me!FormDate.Value, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
Me.Filter = strFilter
FilterOn = True
DoCmd.OpenForm "Maf View", , strFilter
```

Comment: Just don't set `Me.Filter` and `FilterOn` of the report? (i.e. remove those 2 lines)

Comment: I tried removing the two lines.  It didn't filter the report, but I still have the issue of the form opening with no filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm(FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
```

You have `strFilter` in the `FilterName` argument instead of `WhereCondition`. A query name would go there, but not a SQL WHERE condition.

Either do

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Maf View", , , strFilter
```

or - much better readable! - use named parameters:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Maf View", WhereCondition:=strFilter
```